# Java's Double.doubleToLongBits equivalent in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, floating-point

Suppose number: `-58.725`. When calling `Double.doubleToLongBits(-58.725)` it returns: `-4589910410541609779`. How can i get the same result in MySQL?

I have tried: `CONV(CONV(-58.725, 10, 2), 2, 10)` which returns: `18446744073709551558`

Or: `CAST(CONV(CONV(-58.725, 10, 2), 2, 10) as signed)` which returns `-58`.

The end-goal is to be able to extract the exponent and the significand of `-58.725` and others in MySQL. I believe I need the integer value of the IEEE 754 bit representation of any given double/float, to put it in other words.

Comment: I do not work with MySQL, but you should be aware that the exponent and significand of a floating-point representation are different from the bit-fields that are used to encode them. The mathematical significand consists of bits from the primary significand field plus one more derived from the primary exponent field, and the mathematical exponent comes from the exponent field minus a bias. Which you should use depends on your actual end goal—it is not likely your end-goal really is “to be able to extract the exponent and the significand.” What do you want to do with them?…

Comment: … What exponent and significand do you want when the number is subnormal? If are doing something mathematical with these values, you want the normalized significand and correspondingly adjusted exponent. If you are manipulating the encoding in some way, you may want the unnormalized significand.

Comment: How about `select HEX(-58.725) from dual`. Gives me 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFC5 (18446744073709551557)

Comment: @g00se Which is the value I do NOT want. :)

Comment: Right. You're probably going to have to write a function in mysql then

Comment: @EricPostpischil For data migration purposes I'm trying to imitate the rounding behaviour of `new BigDecimal(58.725).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN).doubleValue()` which returns 58.73 in stead of the correct: 58.72, which is returned by `BigDecimal.valueOf(58.725).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN).doubleValue()`. Even though 58.73 might not be the correct rounding, it is still the value I want.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Basically i want the floating-point value of a double value. That means `-58.725 == -58.7250000000000014210854...` and round this up in "HALF_EVEN"/bankers rounding . So it becomes: -58.73